# Should we normalize test data by choosing maximum and minimum value of training data?

Tags: machine-learning, normalization

I'm training my CNN network with one model's data whereas i'm testing it with another model's data. I perform min max normalization on each sample. And every samples ranges [-1,1]. My question is that while performing min-max normalization we pick minimum and maximum value in each sample's features. For the test data should I choose minimum and maximum of each sample Or should I normalize it with  the minimum and maximum value of training data?

Comment: you need to use same max and min that you get from train set and use them in order to rescale your test set

Answer (score 2):

You should use your **training data fit function** (by fit function i mean the function of the scaling that is learning from your data)simply because your test dataset size and feature values could be different than your training which would result in a **scale** different than the **scale** used on your training data. imagine you want to infer your model with 1 row which will be a problem if you try to fit 1 row on the minmaxscaler.

***Example*** : 
Let's say your **max** value is **100** and **min** value is **0** on your **training** data for a particular feature, you scale that to **[0,1]** => **100 will be 1, 0 will stay as so.
70 will be 0.7 , 60 = 0.6 and so on.** You move on to the test set and apply scaling on it **but** it happens that the **max** value for that **same feature** in your test set is **70** ( 100 unfortunately for you happens to exist only in the training set ). Your **70** in the test set if you scale using the test set will be a **1**. You feed the **1 ( 70** ) to your model who's trained to consider a **1 as a 100** thus the error.

Comment: what do you mean by training data fit function? I have 10000 training samples, each samples has 256 features and I normalize each sample 's feature range [-1,1]. In order to perform [-1,1] normalization, I have to pick each minimum and maximum value in each sample's 256 features.  But my test data has only 700 samples. I'm little confused that how can I pick the scale of 10000 samples to normalize 700 samples.

Comment: i'll edit my answer for you to understand better.

Comment: Actually I have total 256 features in one sample (1 row). I am noemalizing these 256 features such that 1st feature is -1 and last feature is 256. That is why i'm confusing while implementing it on test data. I'm not picking the maximum and minimum value of some particular feature. Can you please explain how should I normalize in this case?

Comment: I actually understand what you explained. But my normalization is different from what you explained

Comment: the explanation applies for any transformation(that learns from the data) you apply to your training/test datasets only for one exception when you are sure that your training/test datasets are similar in range

Comment: My training and test data have different ranges but then how to choose standard value to normalize test data because it has only 500 samples and training set has 10000 samples.

Comment: Your model ( trained on training data ) should be fed values following one scale ( learned from your training data ), if , for each test dataset, you want to create a new scale like i explained in my answers, you'll have , after scaling , many 1's fed to the model while they don't represent the max value you trained your model on, but the max value available in your test dataset which will induce errors in predictions.

Comment: I completely understand your question but my question is little different. If I have 1000 training samples at temperature T1 in one model and 50 samples(as test set) at T1 from second model.  can I choose any 50 samples from the training data to normalize 50 samples of test data?

Comment: No, don't normalize using only 50 samples from the training set, take the max-min values from the whole 1000 samples to create the scale! once you have the scale, you can apply it to your 50 samples and get your normalized test data!

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/95187/discussion-between-blenz-and-jerry).

Answer (score 0):

You should always normalize the test data with the parameters/techniques used for training data.

Example from [sklearn link](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.preprocessing.MinMaxScaler.html),

Here, scaler.fit() on the data learns the parameters and normalizes the data using transform.  The same parameters are used to transform the data [2, 2] (test data). The test data size here is irrelevant as the learnt parameters (from training data) are used to convert each of the test samples.

```
>>> from sklearn.preprocessing import MinMaxScaler
>>> data = [[-1, 2], [-0.5, 6], [0, 10], [1, 18]]
>>> scaler = MinMaxScaler()
>>> print(scaler.fit(data))
MinMaxScaler(copy=True, feature_range=(0, 1))
>>> print(scaler.data_max_)
[ 1. 18.]
>>> print(scaler.transform(data))
[[0.   0.  ]
 [0.25 0.25]
 [0.5  0.5 ]
 [1.   1.  ]]
>>> print(scaler.transform([[2, 2]]))
[[1.5 0. ]]
```

Comment: you normalized each feature. My normalization is different. My normalization will generate [[0,1],[0,1],[0,1],[0,1]] instead of assigning 0 each feature's minimum as zero and maximum as 1